# "Фамильные" прилагательные с нарицательным значением

Tags: этимология, классификация

Много ли в русском языке прилагательных, которые произошли тем или иным способом от фамилий известных людей и получили нарицательное значение? В качестве примера пусть будет слово *стахановский*. Стахановское движение возникло в годы первых советских пятилеток и получило свое название по фамилии шахтера Алексея Стаханова. Давайте вспомним побольше таких слов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне вначале вопрос показался простым, но потом поняла, что нужны не просто фамилии, ставшие нарицательными, но еще и прилагательные. Поэтому, скажем, "джакузи" не подойдет.

Мне кажется, что в отдельные группы надо выделить прилагательные, образованные от фамилий:

1. писателей и поэтов. Например, пушкинский стиль, шекспировский драматизм и т.п.;
2. героев произведений (донкихотский поступок, гамлетовский вопрос, плюшкинский угол и т.п.;)
3. ученых, исторических деятелей (рентгеновские лучи, наполеоновские планы, суворовское училище и т.п.)

Думаю, что можно выделить и другие группы.

Comment: Кстати, если, скажем от "Пушкина" легко образовать прилагательное "пушкинский", то что делать, например, с Достоевским?

Comment: Да, проблематично! Сама фамилия Достоевский (и остальные на -кий, -кая) и так похожа на прилагательное :)))))

Comment: В конкретном случае это очень просто : Достоевские чтения.

Comment: А ларчик просто открывался :) 
  Есть сомнения, но, думаю, что можно добавить еще географические названия: Берингов пролив и т.п.

Comment: Добавлю к Вашему ответу еще один пункт. Это разного рода исторические, культурные и торговые "бренды" (иногда антибренды))). Викторианский стиль и эпоха, столыпинские вагон и "галстук", кузнецовский фарфор, смирновская водка, андреевский флаг, нобелевские премия и лауреаты...